# No longer a moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators

Just a notification - I am no longer a community moderator, I've resigned from the position.

As I've [written in my self-nomination](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/3#post-49271):

> if I ever find myself falling beneath a certain reasonable participation threshold - e.g. dropping to just a few visits per week - I will retire

And indeed, since my participation have been slowly dwindling over the last year and a half, it's time to call it a day. This is especially true now when there are many new mods that can easily handle the current load.

As for whether I will be replaced immediately by another mod - that's up to the team and how they feel about the current pressure of flags.

Thanks for your trust! Looking forward to use my normal close votes again!

Comment: D: thank you for your time, man. Are you going to be sticking around as a regular user or will you be taking an extended leave?

Comment: @badp I don't think I'll be reviewing too much, but as I'm still a gamer, I guess I'll still be here to ask and answer regular questions :)

Comment: Thank you for all the time you spent making arqade a better place!

Comment: Cheers for everything :) hope you enjoy contributing down on a ground level with us schmucks :P

Comment: Been there, done that. Although for me it was more the fact I spent too much time on the sites and not enough on other things I was supposed to do.

Comment: @Gnoupi Like actually _playing_ games? Nah, I know what you mean :P

Comment: Oak, how much time investment do you think is needed, as a moderator? I was considering nominating myself, but I'm not sure if I'd devote enough time to it.

Comment: @DCShannon I don't know what the load now here, but back when I was a mod it was usually at most 5 minutes per visits, often less, sometimes more. But that is assuming you visit multiple times every day.